# Arrow on BarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, ios7

On iOS if you do not set the bar button item in the navigation stack manually, one is added for you with the previous controller's title and a back arrow. I want to keep the arrow only. e.g. if my previous controller's title was Hello, my current controller would have the leftbarbuttonitem as "< CustomTitle". Currently, I just have this:

```
           UIBarButtonItem *goBackAndSaveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"[insert arrow here]CustomTitle" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(goBackAndSave)];

             self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = asdf;
```

Is there any way to control the title so I can set a custom title but still use the back arrow"

Comment: FYI - this behavior has existed since iOS 2.0. It has nothing to do with iOS 7.

Comment: @rmaddy: I didn't know, I just recently became a developer. Will update the description. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Can you use `willMoveToParentViewController:` as your trigger instead?

Comment: @Wain: I ended up using viewWillDisappear. If you make your comment an answer, i'll accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a custom bar button item you could alternatively use one of the view controller life cycle methods like `willMoveToParentViewController:` as the trigger for your save. If you use  `willMoveToParentViewController:` (when the parent is nil) you can save once when the view is removed. If you use `viewWillDisappear:` your save will run more frequently when pushing other views.

Answer (score 0):

In the -viewDidLoad method of the controller you're pushing a new view controller from, use this code:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = 
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"CustomTitle"
                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                 target:nil
                                 action:nil];
```

Then when you push your new view controller, its back button will have your custom title.

Comment: Let me clarify. All you have to do is set the title of the back bar button before you push your new view controller onto the navigation controller stack.